# Offroad / 4x4 car rental with camping equipment in Morocco

Tags: car-rentals, camping, morocco, off-road, campers

I am planning to visit Morocco for some weeks. While I find a lot of SUVs to rent, it is hard to find a proper 4x4 car so far. My favorite would be a Toyota Hilux or similar, like it is found in Southern Africa, with Alu Cab and rooftop tent. Does anyone know a company renting something like this?

Also, a company renting camping like tents, mats etc. would be an option.

Comment: Googling 'overlanding morocco rentals' got a range of results you might check out more deeply.

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, half of the companies is not existing anymore, most have not the cars they promise etc. so this is not all off topic question. In this part of the world you do not solve problems with google, you solve problems with contacts. And as I explained, I searched A LOT. And explained in detail, what I find and what not.